# How to identify duplicates within text in two columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet where column A has various names in varying formats:
A1   John Smith
A2   Jones, Mary
A3   Sally Gomez
A4   The Gonzalez family

Column B has similar data:
B1   The Smith Family Trust
B2   Bob and Mary Jones
B3   Blackwell, John
B4   Luz Gonzalez

I would like to identify the instances where the same last name is found in column A and column B. In the examples above, the formula, if placed in column C, would result in
 
C1   TRUE   (because "Smith" is found in both A1 and B1)
C2   TRUE   (because "Jones" is found in both A2 and B2)
C3   FALSE   (because there are no common words between A3 and B3)
C4   TRUE   (because "Gonzalez" is found in both A4 and B4)

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

Given your comments as well as your question, it seems you want to return TRUE if any word in one phrase matches a word in the adjacent phrase.  One way to do this is with a User Defined Function (VBA).  The following excludes any words that are in `arrExclude`, which you can add to as you see fit.  It will also exclude any characters that are not letters, digits or spaces, and any words that consist of just a single character.

See if this works for you.

Another option would be take a look at the free fuzzy lookup add-in provided by MS for excel versions 2007 and later.

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), `alt-F11` opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select `Insert/Module` and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like

```
=WordMatch(A1,B1)
```

in some cell.

**EDIT2:** `Find Matches` segment changed to see if it works better on Mac

---

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0
Option Compare Text
Function WordMatch(S1 As String, S2 As String) As Boolean
    Dim arrExclude() As Variant
    Dim V1 As Variant, V2 As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, S As String
    Dim RE As Object
    Dim sF As String, sS As String

'Will also exclude single letter words
arrExclude = Array("The", "And", "Trust", "Family", "II", "III", "Jr", "Sr", "Mr", "Mrs", "Ms")

'Remove all except letters, digits, and spaces
'remove extra spaces
'Consider whether to retain hyphens

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "[^A-Z0-9 ]+|\b\S\b|\b(?:" & Join(arrExclude, "|") & ")\b"
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = True
End With

With WorksheetFunction
    V1 = Split(.Trim(RE.Replace(S1, "")))
    V2 = Split(.Trim(RE.Replace(S2, "")))
End With

'Find Matches
If UBound(V1) <= UBound(V2) Then
    sS = " " & Join(V2) & " "
    For I = 0 To UBound(V1)
        sF = " " & V1(I) & " "
        If InStr(sS, sF) > 0 Then
            WordMatch = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next I
Else
    sS = " " & Join(V1) & " "
    For I = 0 To UBound(V2)
        sF = " " & V2(I) & " "
        If InStr(sS, sF) > 0 Then
            WordMatch = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next I
End If

WordMatch = False

End Function
```

---

**EDIT:** Here is a screenshot of the results, using both your original examples, and also the examples you gave in a comment below where you indicated you were having a problem.

[image]

Comment: This seems like it should work but I'm getting a #VALUE! error.

Comment: Please provide (copy/paste the two strings) an example where a `#VALUE!` error is being returned by UDF.

Comment: TENANT_NAME            OWNER_NAME           ACRES    Same Last Name?
KUCKARIAN, PHILLIP   EVELYN KUCKARIAN   2.9             #VALUE!
WESTERN PROPERTY  ELLO CORP                 3.9             #VALUE!

Is this what you are looking for? In the first row, the UDF should have returned TRUE, and in the second row FALSE.

I can also upload a screen shot if that would be more helpful. (and thank you for your help)

Comment: @candez I have added a screen shot showing the UDF working with the examples you provided.  Are you certain that both arguments of the UDF refer to cells that are not empty?  Are you certain you placed the UDF in a Regular Module as per the instructions?

Comment: Hmm. I am clearly doing something wrong. I'm using Excel for Mac 2011, if it makes a difference. This is how it appears when I enter the script [link](http://candacernelson.com/images/misc/Script.jpg), and this is where I have entered the UDF [link](http://candacernelson.com/images/misc/Code.jpg). When I hover over the #VALUE! error, it indicates "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type." The text was in a General format, so I switched those columns to Text, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @candez  I am not sure why it works here and not on your machine.  It is possible there is an issue in the `Find Matches` segment with `Application.Match` behaving differently in the two versions.  I will edit my answer to provide a different method (using Regular Expressions) to check for matches, and see if that works better on your machine.

Comment: @candez Edited again so as not to use Regex for the comparison.  I think this version will be more bullet-proof.

Answer (score 1):

The most difficult part of this exercise is determining what, in column A, constitutes a last name. In your example, it's either:

1. The first word, if there's a comma in the whole name
2. The second word

If that rule is true, then you can just do a formula like this:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(FIND(last_name, B1:B4)))
```

The formula to actually determine the last name is a little more complex. You essentially have to figure out what character positions the spaces are in, and then pull the letters in between. There's a good explanation on this thread:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/17559-return-first-second-word-text-string-find-subsitute.html

Comment: Unfortunately there is no real pattern to what the last name is, as there are examples like "Bob and Mary Smith" or "Bob L Smith Et Al" or "Smith Bob L and Mary" with no comma.

But this gives me a direction to head in. Thank you.

Comment: Actually in most cases, a TRUE value any time any single word is repeated, could work. It wouldn't be perfect, as it would incorrectly return a TRUE value when comparing "Bob and Mary Smith" and "John and Linda Jones," or "Bob L Smith" and "Jones, Bob" as TRUE. But in the majority of cases it could work.

Answer (score 0):

In cell C1 use this formula [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399060/excel-two-columns-with-duplicates)

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(B1:B4,A:A,1)=B1,"",B1)
```

Comment: That isn't applicable to this problem.  The solution you referenced is for an exact match of the entire cell contents.  The problem here is for a match of any word that is a portion of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight both columns > conditional formatting (home tab) > highlight cell rules > duplicate values.
This will highlight all duplicates in both columns.
Make sure you are highlighting the columns and not the cells.

Comment: Doesn't this compare the entire cell contents rather than finding a matching word that is a portion of each cell?

Comment: The other challenge with this is that I can't use the results in a formula. Ultimately I would like to create a SUMIF formula based on the TRUE or FALSE result in column C.